# (XMLHttpRequest error) Problem with serverside CORS policy

Tags: dart, http, server, flutter-web

I created a flutter project with a web version and we already have a server for database access that another android/ios app uses. However the web version of the new app is running into problems with cors policy. I've been trying to solve this looking at other stock overflow questions and searching on google without success and was hoping someone can help me figure out what I might be doing wrong.

I've tested making the uri client side both with:

```
String url = "https://" + host + ":" + port;
Uri uri = Uri.parse(url + "/test");
```

and

```
String url = host + ":" + port;
Uri uri = Uri.https(url, "/test");
```

I then call the server using the http/http package:

```
Response response = await get(uri).timeout(const Duration(seconds: 17));
```

As for the structure of the server side code:

```
const createError = require('http-errors');
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const logger = require('morgan');
const https = require('https');

const routerOne = require('./path/to/router/file');
const routerTwo = require('./path/to/router/file');

const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const fs = require("fs");
dotenv.config();

console.log('port' + process.env.PORT);

var key = fs.readFileSync('./certs/key.key');
var cert = fs.readFileSync('./certs/cert.crt');

var options = {
    key: key,
    cert: cert
};

const cors = require('cors');
const app = express();
app.use(cors());

try {
    let server = https.createServer(options, app);
    server.listen(process.env.PORT, () => {
        console.log('Started https server on port ' + process.env.PORT);
    });
} catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
}

app.get('/test', cors(), function (req, res, next) {
  res.json({msg: "This is CORS-enabled for all origins!"})
})

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'pug');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({limit: '50mb', extended: false}));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/router/one', routerOne);
app.use('/router/two', routerTwo);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
    console.log(err);
    // set locals, only providing error in development
    res.locals.message = err.message;
    res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

    // render the error page
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

Unlike android when running web version(Chrome or Edge), I have been unable to get the response from the newly added '/test' on the server side. I'm hoping for some suggestion for how I can get the cors policy to work.

Client side I've tried using Uri.https instead of Uri.parse and I added headers as well.
On the server I tried to follow instructions on how to add cors policy to node.js/express.

**Error message from flutter:**

```
Error: XMLHttpRequest error.
    C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/core_patch.dart 963:28                get current
packages/http/src/browser_client.dart 69:22                                                                                    <fn>
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/zone.dart 1685:54                                              runUnary
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 147:18                                        handleValue
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 766:44                                        handleValueCallback
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 795:13                                        _propagateToListeners
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 557:7                                         [_complete]
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/stream_pipe.dart 61:11                                         _cancelAndValue
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/stream.dart 1530:7                                             <fn>
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/operations.dart 334:14  _checkAndCall
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/operations.dart 339:39  dcall
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/html/dart2js/html_dart2js.dart 37309:58                              <fn>


    at Object.createErrorWithStack (http://localhost:59072/dart_sdk.js:5093:12)
    at Error._throw (http://localhost:59072/dart_sdk.js:20399:18)
    at Error.throwWithStackTrace (http://localhost:59072/dart_sdk.js:20396:18)
    at async._AsyncCallbackEntry.new.callback (http://localhost:59072/dart_sdk.js:40921:18)
    at Object._microtaskLoop (http://localhost:59072/dart_sdk.js:40778:13)
    at _startMicrotaskLoop (http://localhost:59072/dart_sdk.js:40784:13)
    at http://localhost:59072/dart_sdk.js:36261:9
```

**Image of browser:** [image of browser with network tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EuaZT.jpg)

---

**Update Solution**

The answer from Ber is correct. This is a problem with certificate. Self signed certificate was being used on our server and by getting a new certificate using Let's encrypt the problem got solved. If anyone else runs into the "XMLHttpRequest error" they may also want to check out the error output in the browser as the "net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID" was not shown in flutter.

Comment: If you use Express's CORS middleware, do not also set CORS-related headers manually.

Comment: Removed app.use() with all the res.header() to not set the headers, that's not enough for it to work. I believed I was using cors middleware. I installed cors into the node_modules folder and tried using available info on using cors. For example: https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html. The difference here from the example given in the link is that I'm placing the app in server and using listen on server instead of on app. I have the line cors = require('cors'); for using the package. Is there some way I'm supposed to use cors differently in my code for my server calls to work?

Comment: Any examples as to how I should use it?

Comment: Please edit your question to reflect the current state of your code.

Comment: Finished editing my question.

Comment: Thanks. Add also the CORS error message and screenshots of your browser's Network tab.

Comment: Updated question with error message and browser image

Comment: I see no request was even sent; your issue doesn't seem to CORS-related.

Comment: When searching on google using the flutter error message, everything seemed to point to it being related to cors policy. I'm able run the app on android and get server response. Do you have any idea as to what could be causing the error for flutter web?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Flutter at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error code in your screen shot is net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID
meaning the server's SSL certificate is expired, invalid for the domain or not accepted by the root certificates in your app.